# Issue with Minimax Tic-Tac-Toe in Python (returning only similar negative values)

Tags: python, minimax

I've looked at a ton of resources here and elsewhere on the Minimax algorithm, and while I think I mostly understand it now, there is one part that still eludes me. Each end state in the tree propagates its value upward by one: (10 - depth) for the CPU, (-10 + depth) for the 'human', and 0 for a draw. These values are in turn propagated upward to the top of the tree by the alternating CPU and 'human', with the CPU giving the highest value it received, and the human giving the lowest.

However, because the human always plays immediately after the CPU, and the first layer is the CPU testing moves on the *current* board state, the 'human' on the second layer is always returning the lowest value in the tree as the final result for each possible move against the current board. **This results in every current move score (aside from immediate wins) coming out as a large negative number** (I checked with `print`), and the CPU chooses irrationally. I've fixed a few other bugs, but this problem is confusing me even on a conceptual level. The Python code for the relevant bits is as follows:

```
def smart_CPU_choice(self):
    state=self.current_state   #board state is represented by a nine-item list
    turn=self.turn             #alternates between 1 and 0 to denote if CPU or human is active
    player=self.XO_tuple[turn] #gets X or O depending on whose turn it is
    best=[None,-999]
    score=[None,-999]
    depth=0
    for target in range(9):
        if state[target] == '':
            state[target] = player
            score = self.minimax(depth,state,turn)
            state[target]=''
            if score > best[1]:
                best[1] = score
                best[0] = target
    return(best[0])

def minimax(self,depth,state,turn):
    player=self.XO_tuple[turn]
    if self.win_check(True,state) == True and self.players_tuple[turn] == "CPU":return(10 - depth)
    elif self.win_check(True,state)==True and self.players_tuple[turn] != "CPU":return(-10 + depth)
    elif len(''.join(state))==9:return(0)
    scores = []
    for space in range(9):
        if state[space] == '':
            state[space] = player
            if turn==1:scores.append(self.minimax(depth+1,state,0))
            else:scores.append(self.minimax(depth+1,state,1))
            state[space]=''
    if self.players_tuple[turn] == "CPU":return(max(scores))
    else:return(min(scores))
```

I have already tried reversing `min(scores)` and `max(scores)` at the bottom, but to no avail. There are many diagrams about Minimax showing how the CPU will choose a winning move over others, but this doesn't help me, as choosing a winning space when one already exists is the only thing my current algorithm does correctly. It does not intelligently set up wins ahead of time, nor does it ever block my own potential wins. It is only capable of reading the +10 value on the surface and taking the win. I think I'm missing something critical here, but I have no idea what it is. I'm not sure if the code is bugged, per se (though it might be), so much as my understanding of Minimax is missing a vital piece.
**EDIT:** It has occurred to me that perhaps every final score that isn't an instant win is *supposed* to be negative, though that makes me wonder why we even bother passing up positive scores at all. Even so, my scores do not indicate any difference between a space where the human can claim victory, and anything else, so perhaps my problem lies there. After making an apparent fix to the way turns were being alternated, it now never registers and wins downstream for the CPU, and appears to give more simulated moves to the human.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, there *was* a bug in the outside code: my `win_check` was only checking if the player on the current turn had won, regardless of which turn was being *simulated* at the time. However, there was also a bug in the code I posted here, which I only partially fixed with my edit.

Originally I had

```
if turn == 1: turn = 0
else:turn = 1
```

inside the minimax for loop, but this caused the turn to change every time the loop completed, leading to extremely erratic simulations. I fixed this by setting the turn for the next layer when calling the layer, but there was another issue: the `state[space] = player` above it was still setting a letter on the board on behalf of last turn's player. You need last turn's player to be active for the win checking at the top, but the next player acts in the for loop, so I simply placed the turn changer right above the for loop, and called the turn argument on the next minimax using the local turn, as I had originally. The middle of minimax thus became

```
scores = []
if turn == 1: turn = 0
else:turn = 1
player = self.XO_tuple[turn]
for space in range(9):
  if state[space] == '':
    state[space] = player
    scores.append(self.minimax(depth+1,state,turn))
    state[space]=''
```